# Executing the db:seed task for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have the following task:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Drop, create, migrate, seed the database and prepare the test database for rspec"
  task :reset_db => :environment do
    puts "Environment Check: Rails Environment = #{Rails.env}"
    Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    #Rake::Task['db:fixtures:load'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke
    puts 'Seeding Database..'
    Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
  end
end
```

This task works fine up to the last `db:seed` line.
It seems to be using the `test` environment and creates the data there, while all the other tasks execute in the `development` environment. When I execute `rake db:seed` via the command line, it runs correctly in the `development` environment.

How can I prevent it from running in the `test` environment?

Comment: Doesn't the `db:test:prepare` prepare the `test` database?

Comment: oops, i did not know that this sets rails_env as well, yes commenting it out works now ! Please make it an answer so that i can pick it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `db:test:prepare` rake task prepares the test database, and therefore sets `RAILS_ENV=test`.

So the reason why your task gets run in the testing environment is because `db:test:prepare` actually overwrites your `RAILS_ENV` variable.

Comment: You might actually be able to do what you want if you either swap the last two lines (`db:test:prepare` and `db:seed`), or just add a line `RAILS_ENV=development` between them. I'm not 100% sure about this though...

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your seed task as follows:

```
namespace :db do
  task :seed => :environment do
    env_seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', "#{Rails.env}.rb")
    load(env_seed_file) if File.exist?(env_seed_file)
  end
end
```

Now you can do stuff like this (the env-specific file is loaded after the regular seeds file):

```
db
+-- seeds
|   +-- development.rb
|   +-- production.rb
|   +-- staging.rb
+-- seeds.rb
```

Credit: [codeofficer.com](http://codeofficer.com/blog/2010/09/30/Easy-environment-specific-seed-files-in-Rails-3.html)